# How can I back to last url before close app ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, redirect, router

I want to get the last page Url  that user come before they close app. And when they open again, they will redirect to that last Url

I dont know how to get the last url. I try use router event, Ionappbrowser

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the route url in storage and then when app is loaded again, place the method to get that url from storage in the ngOninit lifecycle method.

You use the router to get the url. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router